# Software Raid 5 in Enclosure - Server Crash - Hope?

Tags: windows-server-2008, software-raid, raid5, server-crashes, hardware

I'm a software guy.  I have inherited a Windows 2008 server that had a 4 disk raid enclosure (one of those Rosewill ones from NewEgg I think) connected to it via eSata.  The Windows server was maintaining the raid using its native software raid configuration management tools.  The server has crashed.  Is it possible to take the raid enclosure as it sits and plug it into another windows machine and check or rebuild the array if needed or is the raid essentially dead without the original system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hook the enclosure up to a different machine and use the ["Import foreign disks" functionality of the Disk Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222189). Make sure that it runs the same Windows version as the old, broken machine.

Comment: Thanks - Once the new server is rebuilt and I try this I'll respond here and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Worked like a champ